# Making files and writing in them in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a code to save a table in excel in ".dat" files, with the name of the ".dat" files being the head of the table.

The information under the head of the table should be saved in the file corresponding to the top.

Ex:

`A1  B2  C3  B7
12  78  99  15
13  79  99  15
14  80  99  15
15  81  99  15
16  82  99  15
17  83  99  15
18  84  99  15
19  85  99  15
    86  99  15
    87  99
    88  99
    89  99
        99
        99`

And I'll have *A1.dat* with the numbers 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19.

All is ok but when I select all, in the files i have spaces and the end, like this:

`12 
13 
14 
15 
16 
17 
18 
19 
" "
" "
" "
" "
" "
" "`

There are no " " in the file, I wrote them to underline that there are blank spaces in my files. I don't want those spaces in my files.

Here is the code:

```
Sub salvaremodule2()
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim folderPath As String
Dim file As String
Dim TextFile As Integer

If Len(Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dat-uri\", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dat-uri\"
End If
folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dat-uri\"

Set a = Application.InputBox("Referintele:", Type:=8)
For i = 1 To a.Columns.Count

file = folderPath & (a(i) + ".dat") 'titlu
Open file For Output As #1

Close #1

file = folderPath & (a(i) + ".dat") 'incarcare module in fisiere

Open file For Output As #2

For j = 2 To a.Rows.Count

Print #2, a(j, i)


Next j
Close #2
Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you write to your file by opening an input box, and writing in your input box via code then closing it? I'm not sure what to make of that technique but your problem is that for each column, the `j` loop goes all the way to `a.rows.count` while you should go to the end of the values in the `i` column only.

Comment: I have different methods in mind, select only text or delete the empty lines after I'm done writing the file, but i can't find the code combination.

Comment: If I get your problem right, you need to first loop through all columns (`iCol`), then loop via `while .cell(iRow,iColumn) <> ""` and write each row in your file.